# Logstash in check for array only works with more than 1 element

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

this is mainly because I could not find an answer to this and I want to know how it works/why it works.

Here are my filter examples:

(1):

```
if [message] in ["a","b"] {
      mutate {
          add_field => { "tet" => "world2" }
      }
}
```

This works perfectly fine for messages that are "a" or "b". A new field is added. Perfect.

(2)

```
if [message] == "a" {
      mutate {
          add_field => { "tet" => "world2" }
      }
}
```

Works perfectly fine when the message is "a".

(3)

```
if [message] in ["a"] {
      mutate {
          add_field => { "tet" => "world2" }
      }
}
```

This does not work. If the message is "a" the check still fails and no field is added to my event.

Why does the last check fail? Is this a bug? I imagine that with typing, logstash does not thing that "a" is supposed to be a 1 element array, but I am not sure about that.

If you could also point me to some docs that explain this behaviour :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is some tricky behavior, but I believe I worked out why this is happening. This is probably some unintended behavior created by the double use of square brackets `[]` as array and field name delimiters.

When there are multiple, comma-separated elements between the brackets, logstash reads `["a","b"]` as an array. When there is only one element, logstash reads a field name, so the check `in ["a"]` looks for a field named `"a"` and its value.

---

#### Proof:

Filter:

```
mutate {
    add_field => {'"pop"' => "corn"}
  }
if "corn" in ["pop"] {
 mutate {
    add_tag => ["zing"]
  }
}
```

Input:

```
foo
```

Output:

```
{
       "message" => "foo",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-05T20:08:44.297Z",
          "host" => "4244ed3ff45a",
       "\"pop\"" => "corn",
          "tags" => [
        [0] "zing"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ah - i tried that proof but could not get it to work :D I tried add_field => { "\"pop\'" => "test" } but the escape characters were not accepted. That makes perfect sense - that probably means it is a bug and I think I'll raise it. I've seen heaps of people asking on irc why their in clauses are not working

Comment: I submitted an issue with logstash so that it's documented and known :)